# How to control the indent in endnotes?

Tags: indentation, endnotes

I want to use endnotes in my document. I use, of course, {endnotes} packages, but still don't know how to control the indent. I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.\footnote{Some text. }

\begingroup
\parindent 0pt
\theendnotes
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's precisely how the manual suggests to do it. A bug, imho.

Comment: @Florian Yes, it's a "documentation bug"; probably it remained there also after the setting of the paragraph shape for endnotes was deferred to the `\enoteformat` macro.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The parindent for endnotes is set by the macro `\enoteformat`: instead of restating its (modified) definition, it's simpler to patch it.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\enoteformat}{1.8em}{0pt}{}{}

\begin{document}

Some text. Some text. Some text. Some text.\footnote{Some text. }

\theendnotes

\end{document}
```

The original definition is

```
\def\enoteformat{\rightskip=0pt \leftskip=0pt \parindent=1.8em
  \leavevmode\llap{\makeenmark}}
```

If you want to modify other aspects of endnote typesetting act on this.